# Backbone - how to display collection inside a div in master view element, how to structure a page?

Tags: backbone.js

I want to design a simple page. A flashcards list.

In this I have a list of categories on the left and flashcards  on the right  for selected category. Above I have 2 forms: add category and add flashcard.

The problem is that I have master view #flashcards in which I have everything.

(1) How to display flashcard collection in some inside div.
(2) Maybe I shouldn't have it all in one "master view"? How would you structure such screen so that all would work together?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, having all the logic in only one View is not the proper way to achieve your page.

Usually when you design with Backbone, and start creating all the needed elements what you end up is with more classes than you expected.

In your example I'll suggest:

- **Card**  Model of the card
- **Cards**  Collection storing all the cards in the page
- **CardView**  One View for each card in the page. It will `render` the card and will be listening to User events over its card, like `click`, `remove` and so on.
- **CardsView**  It makes reference to the Collection of cards and is in charge of `render` one CardView by each element in the Collection. Also will be listening to changes in the Collection to see if it has to render a new card.
- **CategorySearchView**  listen to the events in the category search form, fetching new cards according to the *category query*. Or sending instructions to the Cards collection to change attributes into the Models so they will can be shown or hidden.
- **CategoryCreateView**  listening to the events in the card creation form, creating new Card models send them to the server and adding them to the Cards collection.
- **AppView**  a main View to rule them all